# Regex for Apostrophe

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression that will look for Apostrophe in a string. The string can be a sentence too. I tried a simple regex like (') but it only checks for one character in a string. How to I check for the entire string.

For example.

```
"Hello! I have many PC's"
```

will be a match" 
but

```
 "@#%@^@&%@!%!::"";[] I dont have any PCs)"
```

will be a mismatch (basically any character except Apostrophe)"

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're worried about SQL.  Use parameters instead.

Comment: My regex was ''\w+' . I am just a beginner with regex's

Comment: Which language is that? The regex `'` **will** match a single quote anywhere in a string!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so you're looking to see if any string has an apostrophe, `.*["'].*` would match the entire string that contained an apostrophe and `["']` would match just the apostrophes say if you wanted to replace them or whatever and something like this `^["']\w+["']` to match just your first case.

Comment: Why an alternation? Just use a character class (ie, `['"]`)

Comment: Good point was just the way my head was thinking in terms of this or that, thanks have ammended