# Regular expression to match I'm you're he's

Tags: regex

How to use regular expression to match strings like I'm, he's, you're,she's 
XXX'XXX

Comment: It would be helpful to provide sample data and expected output..

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651334/regex-for-apostrophe

Comment: I want to match “ I’m” in sentence “ I’m happy now.”

Comment: Like [`\w+['’]\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/riwkH9/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sol {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+(')[a-zA-Z]+";
        System.out.println(line.replaceAll(pattern, "xxx"));
    }
}

Input:-
I'm Light. I'm 20 years old. We''re blah.

Output:-
xxx Light. xxx 20 years old. We''re blah.

Explanation:-
The above program tries to achieve what you want to do.
Here [a-zA-Z] matches all alphabets whether small or capital
     + means that at least one alphabet should be present
     (') matches a single occurrence of '
```